# Django subquery "ValueError: This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery"

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-filter

So i have the following subquery:

```
default=Subquery(
                        MerchantGroupFee.objects.filter(
                            offer__product__id=OuterRef("id")
                        )
                        .annotate(
                            offers = JSONBAgg(
                                JSONObject(
                                    offer_name=F("offer__name"),
                                    offer_value=F("value")
                                )
                            )
                        )
                        .values(
                            "offers"
                        ).order_by("id")[:10:1]
```

And I have two issues with it
first im getting the error
**ValueError: This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery.**
and second I need that this subquery be capable of receive multiple registers to form a structure like

```
{
   "merchant_offers":[
      {
         "offer_name":"offer_name1",
         "offer_value":100
      },
      {
         "offer_name":"offer_name2",
         "offer_value":269
      }
   ]
}
```

And I'n not sure if  `.order_by("id")[:10:1]`  is the proper way to attempt it.

Thanks in advance if you can help :)